# Can multiple Text objects (in JavaFX) have their style set at once?

Tags: javafx, text, format

For instance, if I have a Text object called foo and another Text object called bar, is there a way to consolidate

```
foo.setFont(Font.font ("Courier New")); 
bar.setFont(Font.font ("Courier New"));
foo.setFill(Color.GREEN); 
bar.setFill(Color.GREEN);
```

And how would it be possible if these Text objects were in an ArrayList?

Comment: sounds very much like a homework question to me - how about re-reading your textbook?

Answer (score 0):

> **Without a List:**

You could use a method with `varargs` to set them:

```
private void setStyles(Text... texts) {
    for (Text text : texts) {
        text.setFont(Font.font("Courier New"));
        text.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    }        
}
```

Now, to set the style for multiple `Text` objects, just pass them all to this method:

```
setStyles(foo, bar);
```

The ellipses (in `Text...`) basically tells the method to accept any number of `Text` objects, so you do not need to call it for each one.

> **With a List:**

This method is almost identical, but accepts a `List<Text>` for the parameter instead:

```
private void setStyles(List<Text> texts) {
    for (Text text : texts) {
        text.setFont(Font.font("Courier New"));
        text.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Now you can just pass your list of objects to the method:

```
setStyles(listOfTexts);
```

> **With Inline Stylesheet:**

Bonus answer: You can also achieve the same result by using the `setStyle` method of your `Text` object. For this, just replace the body of the loop in your method like this:

```
text.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green; -fx-font-family: 'Courier New'");
```